# Como posso descobrir o nome da gpu e cpu no qt c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, clr

Qualquer uma dessas soluçoes me servem, primeiro testei um codigo do system management para tentar encontrar o nome da gpu e cpu, mas da esse erro pra mim no visual studio, o compilador parece nao aceitar o clr, e eu estou usando o qt no projeto com o compilador msvs2017 64bit.

```
Gravidade   Código  Descrição   Projeto Arquivo Linha   Estado de Supressão
Erro    D8016   opções de linha de comando '/clr' e '/EHs' são incompatíveis    Denoiser    C:\Git\Denoiser-Script\src\cl   1
```

Outro problema e que a propia api do qt nao identifica nome da cpu nem gpu, acabei nao encontrando o que queria. Entao qual seria a solução?

codigo que eu usei

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Management;

void printHardwareInfo(String^ HardwareClass, String^ propetyName)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher^ searcher = gcnew ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM" + HardwareClass);
    ManagementObjectCollection^ collection = searcher->Get();

    for each (ManagementObjectSearcher^ object in collection)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(object[propetyName]->ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O comando CLR faz com que seu código faça referência ao runtime do msvc(vcredist) instalado de forma dinâmica equivalente ao '/MD', isso age como um proxy entre o seu código e o CRT. É difícil dizer exatamente o que esse proxy faz, mas acho que ele atua como uma interface para alocações no gerenciador heap, garbage collector e threads. Se você linkar estaticamente ao CRT, o proxy não poderá interceptar suas chamadas para as bibliotecas em tempo de execução.

O [CLR apresenta diversas restrições](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/k8d11d4s(v=vs.140)) inclusive no uso de exceções '/EH', pois o CLR implica de forma redundante. O compilador gerará um erro se '/EHs' for usado após '/CLR'.

Se quiser tornar a sua aplicação estática, terá de usar o comando '/MT'. Porém já tem outro problema, pois o Qt é vinculado dinamicamente. Fora a parte de licenciamento desta framework, você precisaria recompilar o código fonte da mesma de forma estática usando '/MT' já que por padrão é usado '/MD'.